# Flot - images in axis labels?

Tags: graph, charts, highcharts, google-visualization, flot

Is it possible to use images in Flot Charts on either the x or y axis? I have looked at several js chart libraries, but so far only Highcharts seems to have this functionality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Flot charts? You can set useHTML as true, and formatter which allows to return customised elements, like html. Then use CSS to set background / image.